# Mac OS X: how to uninstall PlugSuit

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

PlugSuit seems to make some trouble on my system. Every 10 seconds, I am seeing some error in my Console log:

```
28.06.10 22:32:46 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[156] (net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit.Agent) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
28.06.10 22:29:56 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[156] (net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit.Agent[86943]) posix_spawn("/Users/az/Library/PreferencePanes/PlugSuit.prefPane/Contents/Resources/PlugSuit Agent.app/Contents/MacOS/PlugSuit Agent", ...): No such file or directory
28.06.10 22:29:56 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[156] (net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit.Agent[86943]) Exited with exit code: 1
```

How can I uninstall it? I tried to follow [their descriptions](http://infinite-labs.net/kb/plugsuit/ps-remove-on-10.6.html), however, they all don't work:

- The link to the Afloat update is dead.
- System Preferences doesn't show PlugSuit.
- The PlugSuit installer doesn't give me the Remove option (it is gray and not clickable).

I guess it is maybe only partly on my system (I did an update from 10.5 to 10.6 and only copied my user directory) and thus I cannot uninstall it via their installer. So, how can I remove it otherwise? Just remove the `~/Library/PreferencePanes/PlugSuit.prefPane` directory?

Edit: I cannot remove that directory because it doesn't exist.

Edit: I removed the file `~/Library/Preferences/net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit.plist` but the messages are still there every 10 seconds.

Edit: And I removed `~/Library/LaunchAgents/net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit.Agent.plist`. Again, no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by launchd that is trying to launch a daemon it doesn't find.
launchd uses also files contained in /Library/LaunchDaemons to understand which files should be executed. Verify also the file is not in the directory Library/LaunchAgents (both in the user directory, or in the root directory).

Comment: I have already deleted it from `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. And it is not in `/Library/LaunchAgents`. Any other idea where it could be?

Comment: Ok, a system restart resolved this. Probably launchd was keeping the file in memory or so and thus the deletion has not changed anything. I wonder though how I can tell launchd at runtime that it should recheck and reload the files.

Comment: @Albert: Just removing the plist doesn't stop the job - you'll need to run `launchctl stop net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit` if you've removed the file. Otherwise run `launchctl unload ~/Library/Preferences/net.infinite-labs.PlugSuit.plist` and then remove the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/).

> AppCleaner is a small application which allows you to thoroughly
>   uninstall unwanted apps.

Comment: AppCleaner doesn't list PlugSuit.

Comment: Actually, AppCleaner does list PlugSuit. Just click others. Then run launchctl as suggested above.

Comment: it's exist in apps list second tab then filter by plugins instead of applications
https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/